# Weird Startup Crash On Android Using A Drawable xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-drawable

I have this strange issue where if I try to assign a Drawable xml file to a layout file, then the application crashes. But if i use a standard color code instead, it works fine.

Note. I am pretty much using the template Master/Detail Flow as new, I have also assigned an xml drawable onto the base layout's Root view which works fine. The issue is assigning the Drawable xml onto the list fragment's layout (list_content.xml)

Here is my background xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FF000000"
    android:endColor="#FF555555"
    android:type="linear"
    />
</shape>
```

and my layout is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_lhs"
    >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Loading"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 

            />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/internalEmpty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

^ at the very top you will find the `backgrounds` reference, and the moment I change this to a normal value (eg. `#000000`) it works. I have also tried just having a solid color as the shape in the drawable xml which still cause a crash. The log cat has been little help apart from `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 2521`. There is no visible indication to tell me what is at fault in the logcat nor memory warnings or errors.

Here is the requested logcat

```
05-04 07:03:58.510: D/dalvikvm(1718): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-04 07:03:58.520: E/Trace(1718): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-04 07:03:58.520: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:03:58.520: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:03:58.520: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:03:58.520: W/ActivityThread(1718): Application com.td3.testapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-04 07:03:58.520: I/System.out(1718): Sending WAIT chunk
05-04 07:03:59.173: I/dalvikvm(1718): Debugger is active
05-04 07:03:59.350: I/System.out(1718): Debugger has connected
05-04 07:03:59.350: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:03:59.560: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:03:59.764: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:03:59.970: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:04:00.173: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:04:00.383: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:04:00.594: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:04:00.800: I/System.out(1718): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-04 07:04:01.013: I/System.out(1718): debugger has settled (1362)
05-04 07:04:01.013: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.013: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.040: D/dalvikvm(1718): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 94K, 8% free 2508K/2720K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
05-04 07:04:01.071: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.090: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.100: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.100: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.120: D/libEGL(1718): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
05-04 07:04:01.120: D/(1718): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9518330, tid 1718
05-04 07:04:01.140: D/libEGL(1718): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-04 07:04:01.140: D/libEGL(1718): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
05-04 07:04:01.201: W/EGL_emulation(1718): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-04 07:04:01.220: D/OpenGLRenderer(1718): Enabling debug mode 0
05-04 07:04:01.220: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.231: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.231: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.231: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.231: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.241: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.241: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.241: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.241: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.241: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.241: W/Trace(1718): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-04 07:04:01.251: A/libc(1718): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread        1718 (.td3.testapp)
```

Comment: Whoever down votes needs to stop trolling, its getting old

Comment: Post your logcat trace...

Comment: A couple of things on the gradient strike me as 'odd': the attribute `android:dither` shouldn't be there, as it only applies to bitmap data, not drawables that are dynamically generated. Also, a `radial` gradient with a radius of `0` doesn't sound right. Try setting a positive (float) value.

Comment: Sorry for xml misconception but the code was actually copied from a previous linear gradient but I never bothered fixing values until the crash was sorted. But like I said I have also tried a simple solid shape with 1 attribute... Color

Comment: Downvote ? Seriously, you really think this question is that bad. Read the FAQ please Mr downvoter.

Comment: Just updated with logcat

Comment: also to add @MH, I was on my android replying and didn't see exactly what was going on before i replied with my other reply. But the radius value was initially 700 to give a touch off darkness around the edges, At some point i had changed the value hoping to defeat the crash (no harm in trying). With the dither i just thought turning to false might off helped in memory in someway (incase this was a memory issue) and i wasn't 100% sure if shapes applied (considering the attribute is actually there for a shape). Other than that i have tried all kinds off values but still have it crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stumbling along another issue within this site regards to "error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)" There was an answer on there that seemed to have unexpectedly fixed my issue. The moment I commented out 
    `<uses-sdk />`
It all off a sudden started working, then even after I removed that comment it continued to work, so i don't know if this was a bug or somehow reset something, but i did nothing else but that to solve my issue.